# How create parameterized XPath queries

Tags: postgresql

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  xml_data xml
);

insert into test_table (xml_data) values ('<Node Attr1="Value1"/>');
insert into test_table (xml_data) values ('<Node Attr1="Value2"/>');
```

**Simple query:**

```
select * from test_table 
where 
  xmlexists('//Node[@Attr1="Value1"]' PASSING xml_data)
```

**Question:**

I want use parameter instead const value in Xpath(like this `@Attr1="Value1"`). In Sql server i used sql:variable(like this `@Attr1=sql:variable(@someParam)`). For PostgreSql i can not find equivalent. How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: @kolobok failed